# Technical interview on phone: what kind of question should I expect?

Tags: interviewing, phone

I am currently in contact with a company, in another city from where I am currently working.

I already had a phone interview last week with the HR, which seems to go well since we agree on another interview this week.

This interview will be a technical interview, to test my knowledge and skill as a fullstack developer. It is a big company, with several projects, so I don't know exactly what language I will use, and therefore expect more language agnostic question about general concept of POO rather than a specific question on a specific language.

I already made some technical interviews, with some questions/exercise, such as "what is the complexity of this algorithm? Could you improve it?", but there was always support (pen and paper, blackboard, computer...) and it seems harder for me to answer this kind of things orally.

Is phone technical interview that different from physical technical interview? what kind of question should I expect?

Comment: What's the actual job you're going for? 'Developer' is still quite broad and will influence the questions you'll be asked.

Comment: @Kozaky they have several project and they don't have a specific job with specific task for me, but I will probabbly be a (junior) fullstack developper

Comment: @Kepotx Didn't downvote but I can guess: _what kind of question should I expect_ is asking us to be mind readers :) I would suggest rephrasing to how you can better prepare, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely to be tested on your theoretical knowledge of the appropriate technologies and be asked at a high level how you'd approach certain challenges.

I had a phone tech interview for my current job and it was largely letting them know that I knew how to develop the framework and exhibit a knowledge of the platform, typical challenges, design/coding philosophy, that kind of thing.

Basically, you need to know the theory and be able to communicate your knowledge in a clear, concise manner.

Be prepared to push back on trick questions (it's ok to laugh at these in a knowing fashion if you have a good rapport with them, as long as you **know** they're trick questions and not just dumb questions...).

Answer (score 1):

> Is phone technical interview that different from physical technical
>   interview? what kind of question should I expect?

Other than physical presence, a phone interview is seldom any different.

Expect the same kinds of questions you would get in person. Expect lots of "Tell me about..." questions. You just won't get any "Show me how you..." questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get a single concise accurate answer. Why?

1. We don't know what software you are working with. Is it COBOL? Java? etc.
2. It depends entirely on the people asking the question. There is no standard.

That said, expect questions about basic algorithms and language-centric concepts (like objects or data sets or closures). Web search for "developer questions" and maybe find a list that seems relevant; there are some fairly well known [lists](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NewInterviewQuestionsForSeniorSoftwareEngineers.aspx) out there. It will give you some examples of the questions you would likely face in a phone screening.

As far as the phone versus in-person interview, it could very well be different and if you are going to do both, it almost certainly will be.

Answer (score 0):

**The purpose of a technical phone interview is to weed out people who shouldn't be given in-person all-day interviews.**  Expect questions about technology from people who know technology, "what would you do", and "what did you do", type questions.

What language did you use, what did you do, how long did it take, **do you match your resume**?  Eliminating jokers and unserious people is the entire point to this.

For example if your resume says C++ is one of your professional skills, then me asking questions which test that should be expected.

Assuming you're a good technical match, the best way to blow yourself up is by making mistakes with your soft skills.  Lack of communication skills, some personality defect, clearly expecting that you're not going to succeed, something like that.  The person on the phone may need to work with you.

Good luck.